# SWIFT: Extension for UITextField that doesn't accept whitespace as input

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I know `shouldChangeTextInRange` method on `UITextFieldDelegate` can filter input on `UITextField`, it's ok if i only need to filter one `UITextField`. Now my problem is i have lot of `UITextField` that need to filter whitespace. And i don't want to implement `shouldChangeTextInRange` on every `UIViewController` that have `UITextField` in it. Is there anyway to make extension of the UITextField or other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is quite simple, just subclass `UITextField`, add delegate to it, and implement the `shouldChangeTextInRange` there.

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    delegate = self
  }

  func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if (string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet()) != nil) {
      return false
    } else {
      return true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This has one serious flaw - no other validation is supported. What if you need multiple `BackspaceAcceptedTextField` (strange name for what this does BTW) on a single view controller and each one should accept only a certain number (but different) of characters?

Comment: Ah sorry for that name, i just copy from my last project for this answer, lol, let me change that name. The question just simple, F. Suyuti want a `UITextField` that didn't accept white space and he don't want implement it on every `viewController`. If you need more filter on some `viewController` then you need to ovveride it.

Answer (score 0):

Swift allows to extend the `protocols` as well. You can make an `extension UITextFieldDelegate` and implement your custom code in that method. But there are some limitations, check this answer, it will help you [swift 2.0 - UITextFieldDelegate protocol extension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542362/swift-2-0-uitextfielddelegate-protocol-extension-not-working)

Comment: Thank's, let me learn it, after i found something i will update my question.